# Avoid reversing the array

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I have my SpringBoot JPA repository like below:

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, Long>{

    List<Application> findAllByOrderByApplicationyearDesc();
    
    List<Application> findAllByOrderByApplicationyearAsc();
    
}
```

And my controller is:

```
@GetMapping("/get-data")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Long>> getPieChart() {
    List<Application> apps = appRepository.findAllByOrderByApplicationyearDesc();
    Map<String, Long> graphData = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Application u : apps) {
        graphData.put(u.getApplicationyear().toString(), u.getApplicationyearvalue());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(graphData, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And my javascript on a thymeleaf template (html) is:

```
async function loadChartFromData() {
    var yearDtls = [];
    var countDtls = [];
    try {
        const theResponse = await fetch('/api/get-data');
        const chartData = await theResponse.json();
        Object.entries(chartData).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            yearDtls.push(k);
            countDtls.push(v);
        });
        drawChart(yearDtls, countDtls);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
}
```

Now no matter I use `findAllByOrderByApplicationyearDesc` or `findAllByOrderByApplicationyearAsc` the chart data "always" has ascending data.

[image]

I can get a workaround by using .reverse() like so: `drawChart(yearDtls.reverse(), countDtls.reverse());`

**Question:** Am I missing anything here OR is there a way I can avoid reverse() on browser side?

Comment: You are losing the order of items by using a Map, just return the list you have and work with that

Comment: @Berk, there are other usage of this map in the application. Hence the situation.

Comment: Keys in a JSON object are unordered. Unrelated: `const yearDtls = Object.keys(chartData); const countDtls = Object.values(chartData);`

Comment: @knittl - I tried this. Didn't work. Same ascending data always.

Comment: @AjayKumar yeah, that's why I wrote "unrelated". It doesn't solve your problem, but it makes the codoe shorter and side-effect free

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need the map in your response, you could change your response to something like this.

```
public class GraphResponse {
   List<String> dateList;
   Map<String, Long> graphData;

   public GraphResponse(){}

   public GraphResponse(List<String> dateList, Map<String,Long> graphData){
     this.dateList = dateList;
     this.graphData = graphData;
   }

}
```

Then in your controller you can build the response like this

```
@GetMapping("/get-data/")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Long>> getPieChart() {
    List<Application> apps = appRepository.findAllByOrderByApplicationyearDesc();
    // or call the ascending sorted jpa method if you need it based on query params

    List<String> dateList = new ArrayList();
    Map<String, Long> graphData = new TreeMap<>();

    for (Application u : apps) {
        dates.put(u.getApplicationyear());
        graphData.put(u.getApplicationyear().toString(), u.getApplicationyearvalue());
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new GraphResponse(dateList, graphData), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Finally in the front end when you are using the response

```
async function loadChartFromData() {
    var yearDtls = [];
    var countDtls = [];
    try {
        const theResponse = await fetch('/api/get-data');
        const response = await theResponse.json();

        const dateList = response.dateList;
        const chartData = response.chartData;

        dateList.forEach(d => {
            yearDtls.push(d);
            countDtls.push(chartData[d]);
        });
        
        drawChart(yearDtls, countDtls);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
}
```

This way, we are building the data required for the chart in the order that we got the query result from database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your java code and more precisely the use of `TreeMap`.

As soon as you compute your data in the TreeMap the years as strings will be ordered. To avoid that, you shouldn't change how you query the data but provide a comparator depending on how you want to display the data. See the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Or, it would be probably more convenient to return your data in a `List<GraphDTO>` where a GraphDTO contains the year in string and the associated data. Thus you would always preserve the order of how you  query the data.